# Celery Redis how to prevent task acknowledge if raised an exception

Tags: python, redis, celery

I want to prevent celery from acknowledging task if it raised an exception

setting acks_late didn't make any difference

```
@app.task(acks_late=True)
def send_mail(data):
    raise Exception
```

I tried doing the following

```
class CeleryTask(celery.Task):

    def on_failure(self, exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo : ExceptionInfo):
        
        app.send_task(self.name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass


@app.task(base=CeleryTask)
def send_mail(data):
    raise Exception
```

but that will cause an infinite recursion or I'm missing something for it to be an optimal solution

what is a better solution?

Comment: If task raises an exception, it is finished, and should be ACKed no matter what is your `acks_late` value... If you do not want it to be finished, handle the exception (with try..catch), or implement retrying so Celery re-runs the task if an exception is thrown.

Comment: What about retrying on failure instead of doing such complicated work? try `raise self.retry(countdown=<num_of_retries>)`